# symmetry of probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, symmetry

Let $F$ be the CDF (=cumulated density function) of a continuous random variable, and $f=F^\prime$ be the PDF (=probability density function). Show that $h$ defined by
$$h(x) = \frac{1}{2} \big[\, f(x) + f(-x) \, \big]$$
is also a valid PDF.

**My problem:**  I expected $h(x)$ to have the same support as $f(x)$ -- although this is not stated in the question. However, without assuming that $f(x)$ is an even function, I can only proof this in the limit of an infinit support for $h(x)$.

**What I do:** I decompose $f(x)$ into an even and an odd part, by defining
\begin{align}
f(x) &= e(x) + o(x) \\
e(x) &= \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} \\
o(x) &= \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2} 
\end{align}
We see, that $h(x)$ is just the even part. Therefore, the odd part $o(x)$ must yield zero, if integrated over the support of $f(x)$. However, I can't proof this.

Assuming that the support of $f(x)$ is given by $x \in [a, b]$, I get
\begin{align}
0\stackrel{!}{=} \int_a^b o(x) dx &= ... =  \frac{F(x) + F(-x)}{2} \big|_a^b \\
&= \frac{F(b) + F(-b)}{2} - \frac{F(a) + F(-a)}{2} \\
&= \frac{1 + F(-b) - F(-a)}{2} 
\end{align}
So what is left to proof
$$F(-b) - F(-a) \stackrel{!}{=} -1$$
As I explain above, for $a\to -\infty$ and $b\to +\infty$ this relationship comes straight from the definition if the CDF.

Any chance we can proof this for a finite support?

Comment: You greatly overcomplicate things. To prove that $g(x)$ is a PDF you'd want to check two properties: 1. $g(x)$ is non-negative; 2. $g(x)$ integrates to unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you worry about the support so much. For any r.v. its *pdf* $f$ is $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by simply setting $f(x)=0$ for any $x$ the r.v. cannot take. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{2}[f(x)+f(-x)]dx=\frac{1}{2}[1+1]$?

Answer (score 1):

In fact
$$
h(x)=\frac12[f(x)+f(−x)]
$$
is valid $\text{PDF}$ because

- as $f(x)\ge0$, $h(x)\ge 0$ as well
- $\int_x h(x)\,dx = \frac12\int_x f(x)\,dx + \frac12\int_x f(-x)\,dx = \frac12+\frac12 = 1$

This conditions are sufficient for $h(x)$ to define valid $\text{PDF}$.